# Ruby-On-Rails how to display image uploaded by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload

I am using Carrierwave so that a user can upload an image. I am making a blog website. I have no errors but the image is not appearing. I want the image to appear in the post VIEW. Here is my code:

Post.rb

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

Posts _form.html.erb

```
  <div>
    <%= form_for @post do |f|%>
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
```

image_uploader.rb

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
```

Posts show.html.erb

```
<strong>Image:</strong>
    <%= image_tag @post.image_url%>
</p>
```

When I run my application and view a post it just says Image: with no image underneath it.

UPDATE:

I installed ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick, and when I go to save post it says:

```
1 error prohibited this post from being saved:
Image Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? `Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed`
```

and underneath it displays the image but it wont save the post.

Comment: try @post.image_url.to_s

Comment: @TonyVincent No joy unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While form_for sets encoding multipart automatically, but in my projects I still define it. Try this:

```
<%= form_for(@post, hmtl: { multipart: true } ) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Yay! :D Happy days!